# Refactoring Java Map of Map of Map

Tags: java

I'm reviewing an old code of an project and got a datastructure as bellow using `Map` of `Map` of `Map`(3-Layered Map):

```
// data structure
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> tagTree 
            = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>>();
```

And fetch the values from Map (I think this is the nice part)

```
// fetch at tag values
List<String> tagList1 = tagTree.get("Java").get("Active").get("Tags");
List<String> tagList2 = tagTree.get("Java").get("Latest").get("SubTags");
```

Put the values in Map  (little bit complex and error-prone)

```
// put values
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> javaLangMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
Map<String, List<String>> javaStatusMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> javaTagList = new ArrayList<String>();

javaTagList.add("Java-OOP");
javaTagList.add("Java-Variables");
// put tag list
javaStatusMap.put("Tags", javaTagList);
// put status-wise tag
javaLangMap.put("Active", javaStatusMap);
// put language-wise tag
tagTree.put("Java", javaLangMap);
```

Currently this is serving to maintain following structure

***TagLanguage -> TagStatus -> TagType -> TagList***

I'm planning to refactor this Map because it's hard to read for other developers.

Please share your Idea How to do it by considering following cases:

- All four layer may be changed during runtime.
- All Level should
  accessible
- In-memory solution required i.e. dont use Database table hierarchy .

Comment: I am not sue why you would want to refactor that. Nested generics are good. Just document the method where this belongs well.

Comment: what are the data relation between the three levels of map..

Comment: @redflar3 : TagLanguage -> TagStatus -> TagType

Comment: What about creating objects instead of maps with values?

Comment: Bascially you are looking at: {Java={Active={Tags=[Java-OOP, Java-Variables]}}}

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya Probably because having to manually instantiate nested maps is annoying and error-prone.

Comment: If the number of entries in the Map gets high, you should consider creating objects as @BobTheBuilder suggested, and you can rely on a DB for the querying needs. You can create an object with 4 fields (language, status, type and values). If the entry cont is less and you need super fast lookups like one mentioned above, the current design will be appropriate IMHO. Or you can consider guava Multimap.

Comment: @mmuzahid your project has a DB?

Comment: @mmuzahid When getting data from your data structure, do you always access something like `tagTree.get("Java").get("Active").get("Tags")` or you sometimes need to access `tagTree.get("Java").get("Active")` or `tagTree.get("Java")`?

Comment: @Valentin three possible case ``tagTree.get("Java").get("Active").get("Tags");`` OR ``tagTree.get("Java").get("Active");`` OR ``tagTree.get("Java");``

Comment: @mmuzahid OK, so that rules out a `Multimap<Triple<String,String,String>,String>` solution. You should encapsulate your data structure in some new classes that hide the maps and expose a clean and safe API to your fellow developers.

Comment: @redflar3 Yes, DB exists but in-memory solution is expected.

Comment: @Valentin I'm not used to with ``Multimap``. could you give me some code  as answer for my question PLz

Comment: @mmuzahid The [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) solution I thought of at first wouldn't work for you since you want to be able to access any level.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only ever wanted to access the last level of your data structure, you could use a `Multimap<Triple<String,String,String>,String>`. [`Multimap<K,V>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is a data structure from Guava which basically is a nicer `Map<K,Collection<V>>`. [`Triple<L,M,R>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) is a 3-elements tuple data structure from Apache Commons Lang3 which is `Comparable` and implements `equals`.

You could declare your tag tree like this:

```
Multimap<Triple<String, String, String>, String> tagTree = HashMultimap.create();
```

And then fill it like this:

```
tagTree.put(Triple.of("Java", "Active", "Tags"), "Java-OOP");
tagTree.put(Triple.of("Java", "Active", "Tags"), "Java-Variables");
```

Or:

```
tagTree.putAll(Triple.of("Java", "Active", "Tags"), Arrays.asList("Java-OOP", "Java-Variables"));
```

And then get your values from it like this:

```
Set<String> values = tagTree.get(Triple.of("Java", "Active", "Tags"));
```

---

Here is another rough solution that may suit you which enables to get with 1, 2 or 3 keys:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class ThreeLevelMap<K1, K2, K3, V> {
    private Map<K1, Map<K2, Multimap<K3, V>>> firstLevelMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Pair<K1, K2>, Multimap<K3, V>> secondLevelMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Multimap<Triple<K1, K2, K3>, V> thirdLevelMap = HashMultimap.create();

    public void put(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, V value) {
        thirdLevelMap.put(Triple.of(key1, key2, key3), value);

        final Pair<K1, K2> secondLevelKey = Pair.of(key1, key2);
        Multimap<K3, V> secondLevelContainer = secondLevelMap.get(secondLevelKey);
        if (secondLevelContainer == null) {
            secondLevelContainer = HashMultimap.create();
            secondLevelMap.put(secondLevelKey, secondLevelContainer);
        }
        secondLevelContainer.put(key3, value);

        Map<K2, Multimap<K3, V>> firstLevelContainer = firstLevelMap.get(key1);
        if (firstLevelContainer == null) {
            firstLevelContainer = new HashMap<>();
            firstLevelMap.put(key1, firstLevelContainer);
        }
        firstLevelContainer.put(key2, secondLevelContainer);
    }

    public Collection<V> get(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3) {
        return thirdLevelMap.get(Triple.of(key1, key2, key3));
    }

    public Multimap<K3, V> get(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
        return secondLevelMap.get(Pair.of(key1, key2));
    }

    public Map<K2, Multimap<K3, V>> get(K1 key1) {
        return firstLevelMap.get(key1);
    }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
ThreeLevelMap<String, String, String, String> tlm = new ThreeLevelMap<>();
tlm.put("Java", "Active", "Tags", "Java-OOP");
tlm.put("Java", "Active", "Tags", "Java-Variables");

Map<String, Multimap<String, String>> firstLevelMap = tlm.get("Java");
Multimap<String, String> secondLevelMap = tlm.get("Java", "Active");
Collection<String> tags = tlm.get("Java", "Active", "Tags");
```

I say it is rough because:

- the maps that the `get` methods return are modifiable
- I didn't implement `remove` methods
- I didn't test it a lot

Comment: Thanks... your answer is too cool when only 4th layer is accessible :-)

Comment: @mmuzahid You're welcome. I did add the rough basics of another solution if you'd like to pursue it.

Comment: is it ``Multimap`` or ``MultiMap``?

Comment: [`Multimap` from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: I failed to compile. Could you give me the all import statements of ``public class ThreeLevelMap``?

Comment: I imported
``import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;``
``import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;``
``import com.google.common.collect.Table;``
but still ``Pair`` and ``Triple`` failed to resolve

Comment: You need [Apache Commons Lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) also, like for the first solution. Guava Table isn't required for this solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107463/discussion-between-mmuzahid-and-valentin).

Answer (score 2):

You can create classes witch will hold the data structure

```
public class A {
    Map<String, List<String>> map;
}

public class B {
    Map<String, A> map;
}

Map<String, B> tagTree;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is such a bad solution.
It's just a tree representation, for a tree where every leaf is at level 3.
If this was not the case (different leaf levels, etc.) you would have to build up a tree class structure.

But what I would change is to put everything in a **class**, with a get and set method, including **null-checks**.

In the following code, the `add` method takes care of the error-prone handling of the intermediate level maps, while `get` checks for null values in the intermediate levels:

```
public class TreeStructure {
  Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>> tagTree 
            = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>>>();

  // ... Constructor ...

  // This method adds all intermediate levels if not existing
  public void add(String level1, String level2, String level3) {
    String l1 = tagTree.get(level1);
    if(l1 == null)
      tagTree.put(level1, new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>());
    l1 = tagTree.get(level1);
    String l2 = l1.get(level2),
    if(l2 == null)
      tagTree.put(level2, new Map<String, List<String>>(););
    l2 = l1.get(level2);
    String l3 = l2.get(level3);
    if(l3 == null) l2.add(level3, new ArrayList<>());
  }

  // This method checks, if every intermediate level existed
  // Otherwise, get() returns null, and the next get() would fail
  public String get(String level1, String level2, String level3) {
    String l1 = tagTree.get(level1);
    if(l1 == null)
      return null;
    String l2 = l1.get(level2),
    if(l2 == null)
      return null;
    l2 = l1.get(level2);
    String l3 = l2.get(level3);
    return l3;
  }
}
```

(Code untested)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Map of 3-Tuples:

```
class Tuple3<A,B,C> {
   private A a;
   private B b;
   private C c;
   // getters, setters, constructor
   // make sure equals() and hashCode() are okay
}
```

Note, however, that the Map of Map of Maps can tell you in O(1) whether there are entries for some element by just looking in the outer map. Whereas, with the tuple solution, you can only work with full keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no reason for refactor this `Map` structure. But if possible, it is probably a good idea to encapsulate this `Map` in another `class` and give other developers a clean interface.

```
...

public void addTag(String language, String status, String tag)

public void removeTag(String language, String status, String tag)

public List<String> getTags(String language, String status)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I like most of the solutions suggested above. I think the simpler and efficient the design is - more supportable it will be.

Hence, I used basics - plain object composition to refactor your code.

```
package design;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class JavaTag{
  private String tags;

  JavaTag(String tags){
    this.tags = tags;
  }
 }

class JavaTagStatusList{
  private ArrayList<JavaTag> tagList = new ArrayList<JavaTag>();

  JavaTagStatusList(){

  }

  public void addJavaTag (JavaTag tagObj){
    if (tagObj != null){
        tagList.add(tagObj);
    }
  }
}

class JavaTagStatusMap {
    private HashMap<String, JavaTagStatusList> tagStatusMap = new HashMap<String, JavaTagStatusList>();

    JavaTagStatusMap(){
    }


    public void addTagStatusEntry(String status, JavaTag obj){
      if (tagStatusMap.containsKey(status)){
        tagStatusMap.get(status).addJavaTag(obj);
      }
      else {
        JavaTagStatusList statusList = new JavaTagStatusList();
        statusList.addJavaTag(obj);
        tagStatusMap.put(status, statusList);
    }
  }
}
```

Main:

```
public class MapofMapRefactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      JavaTag tag1 = new JavaTag("Java-OOP");
      JavaTag tag2 = new JavaTag("Java-Variables");

      JavaTagStatusMap statusMap = new JavaTagStatusMap();
      statusMap.addTagStatusEntry("Active", tag1);
      statusMap.addTagStatusEntry("Active", tag2);

      // HashMap of Java Lang Map
      HashMap<String, JavaTagStatusMap> javaLanguageMap = new HashMap<String, JavaTagStatusMap>();
      javaLanguageMap.put("Java", statusMap);   

  }

}
```

Comment: We cant use ``enum JavaStatus`` because it may be changed at runtime(added few more status)

Comment: Understood. Let me edit the example again taking this new information into account.